# reformulating for loop with vectorization or other approach - octave

Tags: for-loop, vectorization, octave, bsxfun

Is there any way to vectorize (or reformulate) each body of the loop in this code:

```
col=load('col-deau'); %load data

h=col(:,8); % corresponding water column
dates=col(:,3); % and its dates

%removing out-of-bound data
days=days(h~=9999.000);
h=h(h~=9999.000);
dates=sort(dates(h~=9999.000));

[k,hcat]=hist(h,nbin); %making classes (k) and boundaries of classes (hcat) of water column automatically

dcat=1:15; % make boundaries for dates
for k=1:length(dcat)-1 % Loop for each date class
    ii=find(dates>=dcat(k)&dates<dcat(k+1));% Counting dates corresponding to the boundaries of each date class
    for j=1:length(hcat)-1                                % Loop over each class of water column
        ij=find(h>=hcat(j)&h<hcat(j+1)); % Count water column corresponding to the boundaries of each water column class
        obs(k,j)=length(intersect(ii,ij));               % Find the size of each intersecting matrix
    end
end
```

I've tried using vectorization, for example, to change this part:

```
for k=1:length(dcat)-1        
    ii=find(dates>=dcat(k)&dates<dcat(k+1))  
endfor
```

with this:

```
nk=1:length(dcat)-1;
ii2=find(dates>=dcat(nk)&dates<dcat(nk+1));
```

and also using bsxfun:

```
ii2=find(bsxfun(@and,bsxfun(@ge,dates,nk),bsxfun(@lt,dates,nk+1)));
```

but to no avail. Both these approaches produce identical output, and do not correspond to that of using for loop (in terms of elements and vector size).

For information, h is a vector which contains water column in meters and dates is a vector (integer with two digits) which contains the dates in which the measurement for a corresponding water column was taken.
The input file can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EomLGYleaNtiGG2iV_9LRt425blxdIsm

As for the output, I want to have ii like this:

```
ii =

   1177
   1178
   1179
   1180
   1181
   1182
   1183
   1184
   1185
   1186
   1187
   1188
   1189
   1190
   1191
   1192
   1193
   1194
   1195
   1196
   1197
   1198
   1199
   1200
   1201
   1202
   1203
   1204
   1205
   1206
   1207
   1208
   1209
   1210
   1211
   1212
   1213
   1214
   1215
   1216
   1217
   1218
   1219
   1220
   1221
   1222
   1223
   1224
   1225
   1226
   1227
   1228
   1229
   1230
   1231
   1232
   1233
   1234
   1235
   1236
   1237
   1238
   1239
   1240
   1241
   1242
   1243
   1244
   1245
   1246
   1247
   1248
   1249
   1250
   1251
   1252
   1253
   1254
   1255
   1256
   1257
   1258
   1259
   1260
   1261
   1262
   1263
   1264
   1265
   1266
   1267
   1268
   1269
   1270
   1271
   1272
```

instead with the first approach I get ii2 which is very different in terms of value and vector size (I can't post the result because the vector size is too big).

Can someone help a desperate newbie here? I just need to reformulate the loop part into a better, more concise version.

If more details need to be added, please feel free to ask me.

Comment: Do you need [hist3](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/hist3.html)?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to throw in some spaghetticode without explanation and represantive input and output. I'm sure this can be solved mich easier

Comment: @rahnema1 no I just need hist to create automatically several classes of data.

Comment: @Andy I've added input file and will soon update with the representative output.

Comment: @MochammadHusniRizal I think that `obs` can be computed using `hist3`.

Comment: @rahnema1 can you elaborate how? and will it then take the obs part out of the for loop?

Comment: Please see the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hist3](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/hist3.html):

```
pkg load statistics
[obs, ~] = hist3([dates(:) h(:)] ,'Edges', {dcat,hcat});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but there's an additional zero row and column vector in this matrix. Would you know somehow a way to rewrite the other loop parts (ii and ij) ?

Comment: You don't need `ii` and `jj` when you have `obs` at hand. As you are seeing here there is no need to loop. Set `result = obs(1:end-1,1:end-1)` to remove zeros.

Comment: You're exactly right. I didn't even realize that, how silly of me. Thanks again! Going to marked your answer as accepted then.