# How to reshape a matrix using if condition and find command?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, octave

Suppose that I have

```
dat_h=[1 0.12; 1 0.77; 2 0.37; 2 0.11; 3 0.44; 3 0.41; 4 0.91; 4 0.71; 5 0.51; 5 1.5]; 
dcat=1:5; 
hcat=[0.1 0.3 0.6 0.8 1.0];
```

I want to have a matrix of

```
nx= 
[ 2 1 1 0 0;
  2 1 0 0 0;
  2 2 0 0 0; 
  2 2 2 1 0; 
  2 2 1 1 1]
```

which contains the number of occurence of every values in second column of `dat_h` that is bigger than each element of `hcat` (in columns), where the rows of `nx` represent `dcat`.

I have tried using this code:

```
for i=1:length(dcat)
  for j=1:length(hcat)
    for k=1:length(dat_h)
      if i==dat_h(k,1)
        nx(i,j)=length(find(dat_h>=hcat(j)));
      else
        continue
      endif
    endfor
  endfor  
endfor
```

What I have is just `nx=1`.

Comment: What is the reason you went back to the nested for loops after this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282096/reformulating-for-loop-with-vectorization-or-other-approach-octave

Comment: @Andy that answer is unrelated with this question. It's just another part of the same code that I'm working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is cumulative 2D histogram. Related to the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54282096/reformulating-for-loop-with-vectorization-or-other-approach-octave) you just need to compute the 2D histogram using [`hist3`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/statistics/function/hist3.html) and then use [`cumsum`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/cumsum.html) to get the cumulative result. Note that [`filplr`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/fliplr.html) is used to accumulate from the end to the begin:

```
dcat = [dcat inf];
hcat = [hcat inf];
pkg load statistics
[obs, ~] = hist3(dat_h ,'Edges', {dcat,hcat});
nx = fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(obs),2));
```

Comment: If I'm using `Edges`, does that mean I'm using `hcat` as boundaries in the histogram?

Comment: Both `hcat` and `dcat` are boundaries. Because it is a 2d  histogram it needs 2 set of edges.

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain what you want with the following one-liner:

```
accumdim ( dat_h(:,1), dat_h(:,2) >= hcat )
```

Have a look at the documentation for accumdim if you'd like to understand how it works.

Comment: Good job! But it may produce undesired output when `dcat` is different than unique values of `dat_h(:,1)`. Consider this example: `dat_h(:,1) = randi([1 14],1,100);dat_h(:,2) = rand(1,100);dcat = linspace(1,14,5);hcat = linspace(0,1,5);`

Comment: In a sense yes, but at the same time assuming inexact indices completely changes the context of the problem from an accumulation exercise to an interpolation / inference one. I don't think this was the context here, and accounting for it is just unnecessary complexity. But in any case, `accumdim` is just one of those nice commands to be aware of anyway, so it's always nice when one spots such a one-liner opportunity, heheh :)